# How to Compile Tensorflow Java API with GPU Support on Windows?

Tags: java, windows, tensorflow, gpu

I have some models build with Tensorflow Java API running on Windows. But, I can't run these models on GPU.

I am trying to compile Tensorflow Java API on Windows following the steps described [here](https://www.tensorflow.org/install/install_java#install_on_windows). But it does not have GPU support or any complementar instruction for that.

Please, could help to solve this issues?

Comment: Hi sir! Did you find an answer to your question? I also have the same question to ask. Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Hello I do not know if the issue is still relevant, but Tensorflow already provides GPU support for Windows. Just make sure you have the correct version of CUDA installed for your version of Java TF and that your GPU has the minimum computing capability.

The CUDA versions might be a little tricky. I tried with both tf 1.12 and tf 1.15. Tf 1.12 worked with CUDA 9.0 and tf 1.15 worked with CUDA 10.0

Answer (score 0):

Windows+Java+GPU is not supported yet. Here is a related github issue https://github.com/tensorflow/tensorflow/issues/10708